# What does username password do in an URL?

Tags: http

From HTTP protocal, a URL can format like this:

```
http://username:password@domain:port/path/to/file;params?qs1=11;qs2=22#frag
```

So I try to visit this url from my chrome:

```
http://bitfish:123123@localhost:3000/a/b/c;params?rs=1#dsf
```

This is screen shot from Wireshark:

[image]

I can not find the information in my TCP package, Broswer seems never send username or password to server.

And from the internet, I can not find an example that user username:password to login.

Can anyone give me an example to send a http request with username:password ？

Comment: HTTP Basic Authentication: https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen so, this is a problem with Chrome, It should write those information in request headers but it didn't?